# You cannot define a correlation name 'enable_googlecheckout_idx' more than once

Tags: magento-1.7, ce-1.7.0.2, catalogsearch

my working site got down last day. 
I found this problem in reports.
I believe there must be a quick fix of this issue.
I would highly appreciate any kind of help, clue, hint to fix this issue. Thanks.

```
a:5:{i:0;s:79:"You cannot define a correlation name 'enable_googlecheckout_idx' more than once";i:1;s:3056:"#0 /var/www/lib/Varien/Db/Select.php(281): Zend_Db_Select->_join('inner join', Array, 'enable_googlech...', Array, NULL)
#1 /var/www/lib/Zend/Db/Select.php(336): Varien_Db_Select->_join('inner join', Array, 'enable_googlech...', Array, NULL)
#2 /var/www/lib/Zend/Db/Select.php(315): Zend_Db_Select->joinInner(Array, 'enable_googlech...', Array, NULL)
#3 /var/www/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Layer/Filter/Attribute.php(70): Zend_Db_Select->join(Array, 'enable_googlech...', Array)
#4 /var/www/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Layer/Filter/Attribute.php(94): Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Layer_Filter_Attribute->applyFilterToCollection(Object(Mage_CatalogSearch_Model_Layer_Filter_Attribute), '1')
#5 /var/www/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Layer/Filter/Abstract.php(91): Mage_Catalog_Model_Layer_Filter_Attribute->apply(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http), Object(Mage_CatalogSearch_Block_Layer_Filter_Attribute))
#6 /var/www/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Layer/Filter/Abstract.php(73): Mage_Catalog_Block_Layer_Filter_Abstract->_initFilter()
#7 /var/www/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Layer/View.php(136): Mage_Catalog_Block_Layer_Filter_Abstract->init()
#8 /var/www/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(238): Mage_Catalog_Block_Layer_View->_prepareLayout()
#9 /var/www/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(456): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->setLayout(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout))
#10 /var/www/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(472): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->createBlock('catalogsearch/l...', 'catalogsearch.l...')
#11 /var/www/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(239): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->addBlock('catalogsearch/l...', 'catalogsearch.l...')
#12 /var/www/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(205): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->_generateBlock(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element), Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
#13 /var/www/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(210): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
#14 /var/www/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(344): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks()
#15 /var/www/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(269): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->generateLayoutBlocks()
#16 /var/www/app/code/core/Mage/CatalogSearch/controllers/ResultController.php(77): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->loadLayout()
#17 /var/www/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(419): Mage_CatalogSearch_ResultController->indexAction()
#18 /var/www/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('index')
#19 /var/www/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(176): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#20 /var/www/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#21 /var/www/app/Mage.php(683): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#22 /var/www/index.php(87): Mage::run('website_dk', 'website')
#23 {main}";s:3:"url";s:114:"/catalogsearch/result/index/?dir=asc&enable_googlecheckout=1&mode=list&order=relevance&price=600-700&q=clip+on+tes";s:11:"script_name";s:10:"/index.php";s:4:"skin";s:6:"danish";}
```

Answer (score 2):

Issue is resolved but I wonder why it was not there before.
I commented below block

```
<block type="catalog/navigation" name="catalog.leftnav" after="currency" template="catalog/navigation/left.phtml"/>
```

in my theme catalog.xml file for

> Catalog Category (Non-Anchor)

It was also in

> Catalog Category (Anchor)

there. But my site has been working fine for last two months with same catalog layout file. But it stopped working yesterday and now started working again by doing this step. **Any one know what was the actual reason?**

Thanks to the [this](http://magentoforall.blogspot.hk/2012/07/magento-error-you-cannot-define.html) post

**Note: Issue was resolved in the morning but appeared again now.**

Answer (score 2):

In my case I had to get ride the block that was `type="catalog/layer_view"` from local.xml and catalog.xml and put my modified `type="catalog/layer_view"` block.

Be sure there is only one block that contain `type="catalog/layer_view"`.

Answer (score -2):

Remove below tag if present in `local.xml`:

```
<block type="catalog/layer_view" name="catalog.leftnav"
    after="sidenav" template="catalog/layer/view.phtml" />
```