# Getting error when show "out of stock" products in last

Tags: magento-1.9, module, event-observer, error, out-of-stock

I have developed Magento module that shows out of stock products in last of catalog page list and I test it in my test website and it works correctly but in other websites **(Magento 1.9.3.7)** I got following error

> **ERROR :** a:5:{i:0;s:64:"You cannot define a correlation name 'sorting_t1' more than once";i:1;s:6125:"#0 /home/resellern/domains/mysite.com/public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Select.php(281): Zend_Db_Select->_join('left join', Array, 'e.entity_id=sor...', Array, NULL)
>
> 1 /home/resellern/domains/mysite.com/public_html/app/code/core/Zend/Db/Select.php(373):
>   Varien_Db_Select->_join('left join', Array, 'e.entity_id=sor...',
>   Array, NULL)
>
> 2  /home/resellern/domains/mysite.com/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Attribute/Source/Table.php(122):
>   Zend_Db_Select->joinLeft(Array, 'e.entity_id=sor...', Array)
>
> 3  /home/resellern/domains/mysite.com/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Product/Collection.php(1595):#2#3

and this is my code that run in **observrer.php**

```
 $toolbar = Mage::getBlockSingleton('catalog/product_list_toolbar');
    if ($toolbar) {
        $products = $observer->getEvent()->getCollection();

        $stockId = Mage_CatalogInventory_Model_Stock::DEFAULT_STOCK_ID;
        $websiteId = Mage::app()->getStore($products->getStoreId())->getWebsiteId();

        $products->getSelect()->joinLeft(
            array('_inv' => $products->getResource()->getTable('cataloginventory/stock_status')),
            "_inv.product_id = e.entity_id and _inv.website_id=$websiteId and _inv.stock_id=$stockId",
            array('stock_status')
        );
        $products->addExpressionAttributeToSelect('in_stock', 'IFNULL(_inv.stock_status,0)', array());

        $products->getSelect()->reset('order');
        $products->getSelect()->order('in_stock DESC');

        if ($toolbar->getCurrentOrder()) {
            $products->addAttributeToSort($toolbar->getCurrentOrder(), $toolbar->getCurrentDirection());
        }
    }

    return $this;
```

I say again this code work in my test and other websites but it doesn't work in the specific website and got an error.

Answer (score 0):

Hey go through below link this might help you: 
[You cannot define a correlation name '*_idx' more than once](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/125156/you-cannot-define-a-correlation-name-idx-more-than-once)

If you find this answer helpful please mark it as solution or upvote thanks.